# Getting IsChecked Property of a CheckBox in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So many examples found and none fit! My list box is a list of Result objects. Results can be checked or unchecked in a listbox to mark them as 'Allowed to 'transmit.

```
<ListBox
     x:Name="FileListBox"
     ItemsSource="{Binding TestResults}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileListTemplate}"
     SelectionMode="Single"
     SelectedItem="{Binding FileListSelected}"
     Background="#FFFFFBE2" />
```

The FileListTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileListTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding FileName}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Machine">
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox x:Name="UploadOK"
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                IsChecked="{Binding CanUpload, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I took out a lot of formatting code to reduce the clutter. So when the check box is checked (or un checked) I need to set a boolean on the object to true or false. But I do not want the ListItem selected just because the checkbox is selected. When the ListItem is selected something else happens. Here is the code for that.

```
    public TestResult FileListSelected
    {
        get
            {
                return selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == selectedItem)
                    return;
                selectedItem = value;                   
                if (!Workspaces.Any(p => p.DisplayName == value.FileName))
                {
                    this.DisplayTestResult(value as TestResult);
                }
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("FileListSelected");
            }
        }
```

And here is the code I bound to for the Checkbox (although it didn't work).

```
    public bool CanUpload
        {
            get { return selectedItem.CanUpload; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem.CanUpload = value;
            }
        }
```

I appreciate you looking at this.

Comment: The CanUpload property is actually defined in the TestResult class? It might also need to fire a PropertyChanged event, in order to update the UI when it changes.

Comment: The code sample is not full. What *didn't work*? Do you get binding errors?  Normally `ItemsSource` is a collection of item viewmodels. Items don't need to know about selected item when you are changing either item `CanUpload` property. Unless you want to have single `CheckBox` which will toggle currently selected in `ListBox` item `CanUpload` property your code doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `MVVM` always check for the following:

1. Add `using System.ComponentModel;` to your ViewModelClass
2. Inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`
3. Always check your DataContext and see the `Output` Window for `BindingErrors`
4. Create Bindings like this:

Example Property:

```
public string Example
{
    get { return _example; }
    set
    {
        _example= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();                
    }
}
```

this will call `OnPropertyChanged` automatically every time a new value is **assigned** (not updated automaticaly once it changes from some other location!)

Make sure your Implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` looks like this:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

for that you also need `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`

Other options to get your code working:

1. Your `TestResults` sould be an `ObservableCollection<TestResult>`
2. TestResult should have a property for `CanUpload` and `FileName` and inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Then on your MainViewModel for example on and ButtonClick your can get the selected files like this:

```
private List<string> GetSelectedFiles()
{
    return TestResults.Where(result => result.CanUpload == true).Select(r => r.FileName).ToList());
}
```

**Note:**

`FileListSelected` is a Property of your `ListBox`'s DataContext which is different to the  `DataContext` of an entry (or at least should be).

`FileListSelected` will then return the selected Item of your `ItemsSource`.

Maybe you can comment on this problem with the row selection/checkbox check and add some detail so I can help you more.

**EDIT: Notify MainWindowViewModel about CheckBox State Changes:**

I see two possible approaches here:

> **USING EVENT**

Add this to your `TestResult` class:

```
public delegate void CheckBoxStateChangedHandler(object sender, CheckBoxStateChangedEventArgs e);

public event CheckBoxStateChangedHandler CheckBoxStateChanged;

public class CheckBoxStateChangedEventArgs
{
    bool CheckBoxChecked { get; set; }        
}
```

Make sure that on creation of a new `TestResult` in your `MainViewModel` you subscribe to that `event`;

```
testResult.CheckBoxStateChanged += CheckBox_StateChanged;
```

Handle what you want to do once the state is changed in `CheckBox_StateChanged`. Note that the argument `e` contains the boolean (Checked) and the corresponding `TestResult` as the sender.

You simply invoke your new Event in the Setter of your `CheckBox.Checked Binding`:

```
public bool Checked
{
    get { return _checked; }
    set
    {
        _checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        CheckBoxStateChanged.Invoke(this, new CheckBoxStateChangedEventArgs() { CheckBoxChecked = value })            
    }
}
```

> **CALL METHOD ON MAINWINDOWVIEWMODEL**

for that you need o create a `static` object of your `MainWindowViewModel` (in your MainViewModel) - don't forget to assigne a value once you create your `MainWindowViewModel`.

```
public static MainViewModel Instance { get; set; }
```

then simply add a public Method as you need:

```
public void CheckBoxValueChanged(bool value, TestResult result)
{
    //Do whatever
}
```

you can also call in from the same spot as the event from above is invoked.

```
public bool Checked
{
    get { return _checked; }
    set
    {
        _checked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.CheckBoxValueChanged(value, this);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only makes sense in a Binding that actually updates the source property, and only if it does not already do that on target property change *by default*. It is redundant for all Bindings involved here.

Comment: I just just looked it up after your edit. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms754356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx thx for pointing it out ! #NeverStopLearing :D

Comment: I guess I was try too hard to minimize and ended up making things more confusing. I have INotifyPropertyChanged and all of what you mentioned in your response. My problem is more of how do I capture the IsChecked property without the ItemSelected Property of the item in the list box. My TestResults are an observable collection. TestResult class does have a property for CanUpload and FileName. What does it take to make the MainWindowViewModel respond to the check box?

Answer (score 0):

```
Internal Class TestResult
{
  ...
  private bool _canUpload;
  public bool CanUpload
  {
    get { return _canUpload; }
    set
    {
      _canUpload = value;
      base.RaisePropertyChanged("CanUpload");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of description around the solution, and why this solves the problem please?